# how to parse data in yaml from column to row

Tags: powershell, awk, sed, grep, text-parsing

My final data after parsing from a yaml file is like this in text file :

```
        - id: 200
          addr: 10.242.57.129/27
        - id: 210
          addr: 10.242.57.161/25
        - id: 300
          addr: 10.244.26.1/24
```

I wanted to convert to this and save it as txt with shell scripting ( bash):

```
200,10.242.57.125,27
210,10.242.57.162,25
300,10.244.26.11,24
```

Can anyone help for that?

Need to get the command shell for this (with awk, grep , sed , ...).

I used the following code but it doesn't work:

```
grep -F -e "id:" | cut -c 14-16 -e "addr:" | cut -c 16-35 ip.txt | paste -d , - -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/-/{N;s~[^0-9]*([0-9]+)\n[^0-9]*([0-9.]+)/([0-9]+)~\1,\2,\3~}' input_file
200,10.242.57.129,27
210,10.242.57.161,25
300,10.244.26.1,24
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the question is also tagged `powershell`, let me offer a native PowerShell solution that uses the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement, whose features resemble that of `awk`:

```
switch -Regex -File file.txt {
  '\bid: (\d+)'            { $id = $Matches.1  }
  '\baddr: ([\d.]+)/(\d+)' { '{0},{1},{2}' -f $id, $Matches.1, $Matches.2  }
}
```

- The [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) is used to access what the branch-conditional regexes matched.
- The [`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) is used to format the output strings.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/[^0-9.\n/]//g;y/\n\//,,/' file
```

Append the next line.

Remove all but id and address.

Replace the newline and `/` with `,`'s.